# How to get a static map searching by city with an specific country

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I'm trying to get a map img from Google Static Maps API,

If I do the following requests:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1536x836&center=+Spain,+Andorra&zoom=8&markers=color:red%7Clabel:D%7C,+Andorra+Spain&key=badKey
center and label variations: +Andorra,+Spain , +Andorra,+ES, +Spain+Andorra, +Andorra+Spain
```

I get always Andorra La Vieja, country Andorra,

I expect to get Andorra, Spain,

The only way I could obtain Andorra Spain is specifying the state / province (Teruel).

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking, this behavior is working as intended which can also be replicated in Geocoding API using the [Geocoder tool](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DAndorra%252C%2520Spain) which returns the country "Andorra" when geocoding the address "Andorra, Spain".

Since the address string "Andorra, Spain" is slightly ambiguous, and there are two addresses that contains "Andorra", the API was only able to return the country Andorra. To have better results, you need to be more specific with your query by also providing the admin levels "Teruel" or "Aragon" or a postal code, as you have also mentioned in your post. See full address result [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DAndorra%252C%2520Spain%252044500).